# Java value of type java.lang.string cannot be converted to jsonobject

Tags: java, php, json, codeigniter, jsonexception

I have an API [(here)](http://mridulahuja.com/api/index.php/cleaner/getCleaner?mobile=1111111111&pass=njnjhbh) that outputs a JSON string as output. I want to parse this JSON. It was working a while ago, but I might have changed something in my API or java code.

**This is the code I'm using:**

Here, `msg` is a string which contains the api response

```
try {
    /* this prints */
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(msg);
    String cleaner_id = jObject.getString("cleaner_id");

   /* but this does not */
   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
catch(Exception e) {
   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

I'm using codeigniter framework in php.

**This is the function in my php model :**

```
public function get_cleaner($mobile, $pass){
    $this->db->select("cleaner.cleaner_id, cleaner.cleaner_name, cleaner.date_of_joining, cleaner.current_address, cleaner.mobile1, cleaner.mobile2, cleaner.date_of_birth, skill.skill_name as cleaner_designation");
    $this->db->from("cleaner");
    $this->db->join('skill', 'cleaner.designation = skill.skill_id', 'left');
    $this->db->where("mobile1", $mobile);
    $this->db->where("user_pass", $pass);
    $data = $this->db->get()->result_array();

    return $data;
}
```

**And this is my php controller :**

```
public function getCleaner(){
    $mobile_no = $this->input->get('mobile');
    $pass = $this->input->get('pass');
    if(!is_null($mobile_no) && !is_null($pass))
    {
        header('Content-Type: application/javascript');
        $data = $this->cleaner_model->get_cleaner($mobile_no, $pass);
        if(!empty($data))
            echo json_encode($data[0]);
        else 
            echo '{"cleaner_id":"-10","cleaner_name":"cleaner_not_found"}';
    }

}
```

I have searched a lot and tried a lot of different solutions I found n web, but none of the solutions I have tried has worked out for me.

**UPDATE :**

[this](http://mridulahuja.com/api/index.php/cleaner/getCleaner?mobile=1111111111&pass=password) gives the error

[this](https://api.github.com/users/mralexgray/repos) gives the error

But

[this](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=chirag%20delhi) **parses fine** and gives me just key not found exception

Github sample json api and my api give the `cannot convert string to json obj` exception, but google maps api doesn't. Is there anything wrong with my api format ??

**FIXED : I finally figured out that my api output had a leading hidden character which caused the parsing error**

**This is a screenshot of the error I receive** (Too big a screenshot, but you get the idea...)

[image]

Comment: Sorry...I've added it now.

Comment: Do you use org.json.JSONObject class or org.json.simple.JSONObject. ?

Comment: Why is your content type `application/javascript` instead of `application/json`?

Comment: I'tried using application/json but it didn't change anything

Comment: And i'm using org.json.JSONObject

Comment: Any help guys ???

Comment: You may try to use a different library, for example
http://java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjsonlibjar.htm

Answer (score 0):

I tried to solve the issue, nothing worked for me and I don't know why! I have a solution but I don't know if it does make sense!

```
    try{
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("http://mridulahuja.com/api/index.php/cleaner/getCleaner?mobile=1111111111&pass=njnjhbh").openConnection();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String line = reader.readLine();
        if(line != null){
            line = line.substring(line.indexOf("{"));
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(line);
            System.out.println(obj.getString("cleaner_name"));
        }
        reader.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```